# Complete a Workflow without Terminating

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I'm crating a custom SharePoint 2013 Workflow. There are multiple conditions under which the workflow can end.

I'm using the `TerminateWorkflow` activity, and while that is working, the internal status of the workflow is set to `Terminated`. This makes it sound like the workflow was ended by an external action (or at least in an unexpected way), but that is not the case.

The other options involve using control flow structures such that if the workflow needs to end, there is no more work to be done and it would end naturally (e.g. Nesting all remaining activities in an If/Else control flow, setting a variable to determine if execution should continue and constantly checking the value of the variable, or use a try/catch and swallow the exception, etc).

What I don't like about these options are that they hurt the readability of the Workflow, should another developer need to come behind me and modify it. Ideally I would like an activity that I can use to gracefully end the workflow -- set the internal status of the task to `Completed` and stop further execution, something analogous to a `return` statement in a method.